# Not able to create Generative AI model which will read the resume and check if it matches the job role

Tags: huggingface, google-generativeai

I am new to Generative AI and I am trying to create a model which will read the resume and check if it matches the job role. I have implemented the code but when I run it, the result which I am getting is not acurate. I am using models from HugginFace, this is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from langchain import HuggingFaceHub
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
from langchain.chains import LLMChain, SequentialChain
from langchain_community.document_loaders import UnstructuredWordDocumentLoader

doc= UnstructuredWordDocumentLoader(r'C:\Users\Lijin Durairaj\Desktop\resume.docx')
_data=doc.load()
_resume=_data[0].page_content


model_name='google/flan-t5-base'
huggin_face_api_token='**************************************'

client=HuggingFaceHub(
    huggingfacehub_api_token=huggin_face_api_token,
    repo_id=model_name,
    model_kwargs={
        'temperature':0.7        
    }
)


template=PromptTemplate(
input_variables=['job_position','resume'],
template='evaluate the resume: {resume} and tell me if the candidate is suitable for 
the position of {job_position}'
)

chain=LLMChain(llm=client,prompt=template)
chain.run({
    'resume':_resume
})
```

Am I missing something,

1. Is my prompting template wrong? if no, then how to improve it
2. Am i using the right model? Do i have to use some other model
3. do i have to change the approach
4. should i have to do any data cleaning and feature extraction?

please help me to reach to the solution